# Why won't nginx accept more than 1024 connections from apache bench

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp, clojure, benchmarking

I have a clojure/jetty server (on port 8081) and proxy to it with nginx (port 8080). I've been trying to benchmark the clojure app in isolation as well as nginx, in its proxy role.

When I run the test against clojure directly, I might get `Connection reset by peer`, one in 10 runs. Generally, the tests complete, and performance is acceptable.

```
$ ulimit -n 4096
$ ab -n 20000 -c 2048 -k localhost:8081
...
Concurrency Level:      2048
Time taken for tests:   8.713 seconds
Complete requests:      20000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    20000
Total transferred:      15160000 bytes
HTML transferred:       11720000 bytes
Requests per second:    2295.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       892.208 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.436 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1699.16 [Kbytes/sec] received
...
```

I began testing the full local configuration, nginx on port 8080 and clojure on 8081. Things went well, until I exceeded 1024 concurrent connections.

I noticed, using `ss -tl`, that Receive queues aren't spiking, or at least if they are it's in a flash. But I did discover, using `netstat -s`, that a lot of TCP RSTs are being sent. Occassionally, `dmesg` tells me that it looks like there's a SYN flood. Also, nginx is responding with HTTP status 499, which is supposed to indicate that the client close the connection...

So, my diagnostics are crossed, both apache bench and nginx claim that the other side closed the connection!?

```
$ ulimit -n 4096
$ ab -n 20000 -c 2048 -k localhost:8080
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1528965 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (104)
Total of 26 requests completed
```

### Configuration

I set ulimit max open files for nginx and clojure to 4096.

#### Futile network changes

```
net.core.netdev_max_backlog=30000
# yes, we are using jumbo frames
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing=1

net.core.somaxconn=4096
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=4096     61000
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=2048
```

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  use epoll;
}

http {

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_requests 1000;
  keepalive_timeout  65;


  gzip  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary off;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml text/javascript application/javascript application/json text/mathml;
  gzip_min_length  1000;
  gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


  variables_hash_max_size 1024;
  variables_hash_bucket_size 64;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  types_hash_bucket_size 64;



  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ups

```
upstream ups {
  server localhost:8081 fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
  listen 8080 backlog=1024;

  server_name example.com;

  proxy_buffer_size   128k;
  proxy_buffers   4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

  client_max_body_size 3M;

  large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;

  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;
  send_timeout 300;
  keepalive_timeout 300;

  server_tokens off;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/ups_access.log enhanced-combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/ups_error.log;
  root /apps/ups/current/public/;

  error_page 403 /errors/403_maintenance.html;
  error_page 500 /errors/500.html;
  location ^~ /errors/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $request_uuid;
    satisfy any;
    allow all;
  }

  location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $request_uuid;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }


    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://ups;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to increase backlog `listen 8080 backlog=1024;`

Comment: And second variant, try to leave `backlog=1024`, change `worker_processes` to 1 and add to `events` section `multi_accept on;` and `accept_mutex off;`

Comment: I guess you should increase Worker connections

Comment: @Terra I tried both configuration changes, same results

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tried setting workers from 2 to 3 and went from processing 24 requests to 1054, but in the end I got the same error. I tried going up to 4, but I still only processed 1054 requests.

Comment: I found that increasing `worker_processes` to 3 and `accept_mutex` to off allowed me to accept connections, but the throughput dropped to below 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Terra almost had the answer that wound up working out.

- `accept_mutex off;`
- `worker_connections 4096;`

I tried adding each change, by itself, and reloading, but I still saw the same error. It wasn't until I changed both, that I could push past 1024 connections.

It seems like, because of the proxy, I need to have twice as many worker connections, as I intend to accept.